# mvcSiteMap Bootstrap showing links based on user roles without using User.IsInRole

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

Firstly, apologies for the rubbish question title.

Based on the example [here](http://joeylicc.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/asp-net-mvc-menu-using-site-map-provider-bootstrap-navbar/), I have a menu which displays nav submenu links depending on the users role. This is a line from the mvc.sitemap file. 'userRole' is a custom attribute to indicate which role can see this url.

```
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customers" controller="Home" action="Index" 
area="Customers" userRole="Customers">
```

and in BootstrapMenuHelperModel.cshtml (again, based on the above example), I have a line which contains:

```
  if ( User.IsInRole(node.Attributes["userRole"].ToString())
    {
     ...show url
```

which determines whether the node/nav item item should be displayed.

This all works fine. However, the db is being accessed every time I call User.IsInRole(), and I'd like to avoid this by passing a collection of the user's roles to the View which I can then use to check. The model for the view `@model MenuHelperModel` is in `MvcSiteMapProvider.dll` which I can't modify as it's a part of a Nuget package.

So the question is: How can I access or somehow pass the current user's roles to the view bearing in mind I can't modify the view's model?

Comment: if you can't alter the model I would pass them through the viewbag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security trimming is a built in feature of MvcSiteMapProvider. If you are using the AuthorizeAttribute to define which actions have, it will automatically hide the nodes that the user doesn't have access to.

Security trimming is disabled by default. The first thing you need to do is enable it.

Internal DI (web.config):

```
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_SecurityTrimmingEnabled" value="true"/>
```

External DI (in MvcSiteMapProvider module):

```
bool securityTrimmingEnabled = true; // First line in the module
```

Then you should put the MVC [Authorize] attribute on each of the action methods that you want to secure. In MVC4 or higher, it is recommended that you register [AuthoirizeAttribute] globally and then use the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to selectively allow action methods to be allowed by non-authenticated users. This will ensure you have a white list security rather than black list security.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}

[Authorize(Roles="Admin,Manager")]
public class MyController
{
    // Everyone has access
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Only Admin and Manager roles have access, everyone else is denied
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class MyController2
{
    // Only Customers have access
    [Authorize(Roles="Customers")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // All authenticated users have access
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

There is nothing special you need to do with your node configuration - the security is done entirely on the Controllers and Actions.

Once this is set up, not only are your links hidden appropriately, but the user will also get the 401 status when navigating to a controller action they don't have access to and MVC will automatically redirect them to the login page.

If what you are doing is trying to reinvent security for MVC, there are other options. But keep in mind this will most likely not be as secure as using the AuthorizeAttribute.

## Option 1

If you build the nodes in code (by implementing [IDynamicNodeProvider](http://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider) or ISiteMapNodeProvider) rather than using XML to configure your nodes, you can attach any object type you want to the node as a custom attribute. Knowing this, you could potentially create an object that contains logic that is shared between nodes. So you could call a user cache or session object that contains your roles.

```
public class MyDynamicNodeProvider 
    : DynamicNodeProviderBase 
{ 
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node) 
    {
        // Object to get the current user's roles
        var userRoleRetriever = new UserRoleRetriever();

        using (var storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities())
        {
            // Create a node for each album 
            foreach (var album in storeDB.Albums.Include("Genre")) 
            { 
                DynamicNode dynamicNode = new DynamicNode(); 
                dynamicNode.Title = album.Title; 
                dynamicNode.ParentKey = "Genre_" + album.Genre.Name; 
                dynamicNode.RouteValues.Add("id", album.AlbumId);

                // Add the same instance of userRoleRetriever to every node
                dynamicNode.Attributes.Add("userRoleRetriever", userRoleRetriever);

                yield return dynamicNode;
            }
        }
    } 
}

public class UserRoleRetriever
{
    // This method will retrieve and cache each user's roles separately. 
    // You can tweak the cache timeouts and cache dependencies or change
    // to use session state if that is what you prefer.
    public IEnumerable<string> GetRoles()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.Name;
        var key = "UserRoles_" + userName;
        var result = HttpContext.Cache[key];
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = // Retrieve list of roles here ;
            HttpContext.Cache.Insert(key, result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string roleName)
    {
        var roles = GetRoles();
        return roles.Contains(roleName);
    }
}
```

Then you can call the logic in your custom object by casting it back to your object type.

```
var retriever = (UserRoleRetriever)node.Attributes["userRoleRetriever"];
var roles = retriever.GetRoles();
var isCustomer = retriever.IsInRole("Customers");
```

## Option 2

Build a custom extension method to get the roles.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static bool IsUserInRole(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string roleName)
    {
        var retriever = new UserRoleRetriever();
        return retriever.IsInRole(roleName);
    }
}
```

And then call it from your view.

```
@var isCustomer = Html.IsUserInRole("Customers")
```

However you do it, I think the part you are missing is the caching to ensure your database isn't hit on each request. But exactly how long you cache, where you cache, and whether to use cache or session depends on your requirements and application design.